# How to do a where clause in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a call to my database with a where clause in Laravel 4.  Sounds simple enough, but I'm getting an error that makes no sense.  This call works:

```
return MainContact::all();
```

When I view that page, I get a JSON representation of my data, with all of my data, like you'd expect.  It includes this:

```
... "flag":1 ...
```

So when I try to do this, as explained in the Laravel documentation:

```
return MainContact::where('flag', '=', '1');
```

you would think it would work, but it doesn't.  I've tried the number as both a string and integer, and neither works.  I get this error:

```
ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string in 
/Users/universal/Sites/universalLaser/leads/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/
Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php line 351
```

Has something changed with where clauses in Laravel 4?  Or am I not understanding how to do them?

Comment: try return MainContact::where('flag', '=', '1')->first(); but i have no experience with L4 yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have you tried:

```
return MainContact::where('flag', '=', '1')->get();
```

or more simply:

```
return MainContact::where_flag(1)->get();
```

Comment: The second one doesn't work, but the first one does.  Thanks, aowie1!

Comment: well i converted the value to an integer there, that may be the issue. also, you can use ->first() instead of get() to return a single record

Comment: The laravel shortcut for "where field" is MainContact::whereFlag(1)->get();

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `get()` method on the end there.

```
return MainContact::where('flag', '=', '1')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for guide!

I use the categories table:

- id
- name
- parent_id

And route via:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Categories::where('parent_id', '>', 0);
});
```

A return error is Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

So I try ->get() in end code it is working.